# How to use PowerShell Get-ChildItem to retrieve files AND folders?

Tags: powershell

I'm using the Get-ChildItem command in a script.  I just noticed that it will return file names beginning with bernie3_first or bernie3_second, but not folders.  How can this be modified to return folders as well?

```
$FileNames = Get-ChildItem -Path $FilePath -Include bernie3_first*,bernie3_second* -File -Recurse | select BaseName
```

Comment: Remove the -File parameter, you are specifying only files with that.

Answer (score 1):

Your code shows a parameter that is filtering the results to only show the files and not folders. Filter parameter is `-File`.

Here an example:

```
# This would get content of C:\Test, files and folders
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Test

# This would get content of C:\Test, only folders
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Test -Directory

# This would get content of C:\Test, only files
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Test -File
```

If you want to read more about each of the parameters [you can check this on the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-5.1).

Comment: Thanks, I should have cought that!

Comment: No worries, we all sometimes stuck :). Please mark answer as correct if that solved your inquiry. Thanks